Cannot resolve symbol 'ProcessHandle' on Android Studio
For some strange reason, I cannot make ProcessHandle be resolved in my Android Studio environment:
Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12071903, built on July 11, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 5120M
Cores: 8
Registry:
  ide.instant.shutdown=false
Non-Bundled Plugins:
  PlantUML integration (7.10.1-IJ2023.2)
  com.intellij.marketplace (241.17890.43)
  Lombook Plugin (241.18034.62)
  com.cmgapps.intellij.proguard-retrace-unscambler (1.9.1)
  Docker (241.18034.82)
  SequenceDiagram (3.0.12)
  com.kn.diagrams.generator.generator (2022.2.0)

As soon as I add a reference to ProcessHandle (along with the required import statement):
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.lang.ProcessHandle;

I get this error:

Cannot resolve symbol 'ProcessHandle'


Knowing that 'ProcessHandle' has only been introduced to Java since Java 9 and that I had a Java 8 installed on my system, I first resorted to uninstalling any remnant of Java 8, hoping that this would remove any conflict which I haven't been able to spot by inspecting Settings and Project Structure.
That didn't help.
So, I started trying all sorts of steps based on my SO research (e.g. java.lang.ProcessHandle - compilation error , Intellij Cannot resolve symbol on import ) :

Verified Java Version in Android Studio (AS): Ensured that Android Studio is correctly configured to use Java 17 (via Project Structure settings).

I even made sure the %JAVA_HOME% points to the same location as AS Settings: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr:


Checked Module Settings: I made sure that the module settings in my project are set to use Java 17 as well.




I even placed in the code System.out.println("JUnit5's Java Runtime Version: " + System.getProperty("java.version")); that actually shows in runtime that actual Java version used is 17.
Invalidated Caches and Restart.

None of these measures helped. Any idea what I could have missed?

try invalidate cache and restart option

@PouyaRezaei See step #5 in the OP. I even tried Invalidate Caches and Restart in between the steps, clean build and rebuild. None helped.

Looking at the Android documentation, it looks like this is just not available on Android.

What are you trying to do with ProcessHandle? Perhaps there is a different API to do that on Android.

@Sweeper I have already found a workaround that avoids the use of ProcessHandle. I find it disturbing, however, that I don't understand what's going on with this particular import. I am actually using it in a JUnit test. I know that different subsystems could use different JDKs but AFAIK I made sure that only one JDK is used throughout the system.

What's hard to understand about "it's simply not available on Android"?

And why is that "disturbing"?  The regular Java SE and Android Java platforms are different.  End of story.

@Sweeper LOL, you're right. I found it hard to believe that Android's Java is missing components available in Java (not just any library but a lang one!). I am learning something new every day... Please post this as an answer and I will accept it.

The Android documentation for the java.lang package does not include ProcessHandle as an interface in that package. ProcessHandle is simply not available on Android. See also this section which says:

Which Java APIs can I use in my Java or Kotlin source code?
An Android application can use some of the APIs defined in a JDK, but
not all of them. The Android SDK defines implementations of many Java
library functions as part of its available APIs.

Wikipedia describes some more differences.

Presumably, ProcessHandle is not available because Android apps are sandboxed and are designed to only have limited access to the OS. Android has its own APIs for dealing with processes, such as android.os.Process and android.app.ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.

Thank you so much for this comprehensive overview of the differences between Android  and SE Java. I am going to use this as a reference whenever I encounter a related issue. Why I haven't encountered this earlier is beyond me.
